# Parse JSON with custom structure in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How would one parse this JSON in jQuery:

```
{"3":[
 {"project_id":27,"name":"Name1"},
 {"project_id":28,"name":"Name2"},
 {"project_id":29,"name":"Name3"},
 {"project_id":32,"name":"Name4"}
]}
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"?

Comment: The same way you parse any other JSON.

Comment: There's nothing to parse...that's the literal notation for an `object` in JavaScript

Comment: Please try to read examples for jQuery.parseJSON and here is a link - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) or maybe [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Comment: Sorry, new to parsing json.  I didn't realize the insults would flow so easily.  thanks to those who took the time to answer the question. I saw the "How to parse JSON in JavaScript" but it wasn't quite working so I thought I'd ask.  I thought that that was what this site was for.  Here is what the internet has become "Let me post insults because in real world I'm an arrogant self-centered idiot."

Comment: @ansible: You got quite some negative feedback because it was not very clear what your problem is. The more time you invest in your question and explain your problem, the more positive reactions you usually get. For example, if you had explained that you tried the solution of the other question but that it did not work for you because of X and that you want to do Y, I'm sure the questions wouldn't have been received so badly. Stack Overflow gets lots of low-quality questions and we don't have the time to figure out first what the question is actually about.

Comment: @webbydevy: No one is insulting you.  Your question was down-voted because you didn't explain yourself very well.  You need to do more than just "here's an object, how I use this"?  You need to show where the object (in this case, *not* actually JSON) is coming from, how you're trying to use it, what you tried, and what errors you got.  We are only going to put effort into answers if you put effort into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON data (for example, that returned from an AJAX call) is automatically "parsed" into a structure which is connected to a variable. Or, you can take a string and turn it into a structure using what Adrian showed.

Now, there is one thing about your structure that is problematic: "3" is, as far as I know, not an OK name within an associative array. Change that to "list" or something that meets the requirements of keys like so:

```
var projects = {"list":[
 {"project_id":27,"name":"Name1"},
 {"project_id":28,"name":"Name2"},
 {"project_id":29,"name":"Name3"},
 {"project_id":32,"name":"Name4"}
]};
```

Then you could access the elements like so.

```
console.log(projects.list);
console.log(projects.list[0].project_id, projects.list[0].name);
```

Comment: Why is `"3"` not an OK name?  `var a = {"3": "test"};` works 100% fine (NOTE: You can access objects using `[]`).  Also, JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays", it has "objects".

Comment: Good question. When I tried it in a jsFiddle with his JSON unchanged, I got an error when trying to access it like so: "console.log(projects.3);"

But you can access it like so: console.log(projects["3"]); so it's clearly not "wrong", just a little more cumbersome. So I stand corrected on saying that it's, "Not OK."

Answer (score 0):

The same way we parse JSON every day, Pinky:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you parse JSON using JQuery like this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you need but you can access the elements within the object by core JavaScript. You dont need jQuery for that. For example:

```
theObject[3][0].product_id
```

would return 27

Comment: Don't you mean `thatObject[3][0].product_id`?

Comment: Thank you for being nice and for pointing me in the right direction.